# typescript extend new property without modifying existing type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code

```
type VehicleDetails = {made: string}

function doSomethingWithVehicleDetails (details: VehicleDetails) { //what to add here for newProperty?
  console.log(details);
}

doSomethingWithVehicleDetails({ made: '123', newProperty: true })
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIDVoAsCWBjANtAItUBDFDAZ1gF5YBvAW3wBNoAuWY0AJxQDsBzAXxABmAV05pQKAPadYdCQGUJ1PKh4B1FKCSJUmHHkIlYACgYEixZtvRZcZkgEoqsAPTOA7knyhYoCbHp0sEjQbHACEmywnNBuAApsEjBsEAD8wLCwaFLEElgAdBgS3Cb65vYA3MD8wLIKSppc3OqaVrq2BsRGlLC0DMwA5ACMAEwAzP0ANFEx8YkhEMzsQnC89kA

without modifying `type VehicleDetails = {made: string}`, how can I add newProperty in `doSomethingWithVehicleDetails` argument to fix the error?

Comment: Is `newProperty` needed by `doSomethingWithVehicleDetails`, or you just want it to be tolerant to extra properties, but it does not need them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
type VehicleDetails = {made: string};

function doSomethingWithVehicleDetails (details: VehicleDetails & { newProperty: boolean }) { 
  console.log(details);
}

doSomethingWithVehicleDetails({ made: '123', newProperty: true });
```